# Hard surface modeling - Knife

Tags: topology, subdivision-surface

So what to do. I have a problem with topology. I'm still getting used to a 3D way of thinking. I was fixing topology on the other side of the knife, dissolving edges to keep the shape smooth (deleting part of the loop cut). The problem occurs when I have a transition from smooth to not so smooth :D.

[image]

If it's possible draw the lines on how to retopology my knife.

Comment: Hello, please show the real object and maybe share your file, it's hard to understand what you want and what's the problem

Comment: .. unless you have a reason ( e.g. printing,  other export, or the nature of the original ) it will be both more realistic and easier to model the separate parts of the knife as separate parts in the model.

Comment: I don't know whats going on with the rest of the model but can you dissolve the edge loop that ends at number 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Subdivision Surface modifier (which it looks like you are using) smoothes the object based on the average of the points. So in order to make a crease look sharper, add more geometry there. You can do this with a loop cut by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. There are also many other ways.

But then again, as mentioned by @RobinBetts, it is much easier to make the handle and blade separately, apply the modifiers, and then join them together.

Comment: I forgot to mention this. Another way that you can do this is to mark edges as creased. Select the edges that need to be sharper (less rounded) and press shift-e. Then you can change the crease value. A higher crease value will be less affected by the modifier.